# Provide general JavaScript function with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, qt, qwebview

is there a way to provide a global JavaScript function in an Angular App, which can be called by non-Angular JS code?

Background:  Our Angular app is running inside a webview of a Qt application.  Now we are investigating possibilities to provide an API, so that the Qt application can call functions of the Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

Any front-end javascript code (including Angular) has access to global objects `window` and `document`. You can add any function or property into those 2.

```js
window.myAPI = {
   doIt: function () {...},
   doItBetter: function () {...}
}
```

I'm not familiar with QT WebView, so I can not help you to understand if you can get access `window` or `document` from the QT code. I would rather expect you can.

As another solution - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage. Don't know if QT code can react to those messages.